# How much of glacier ice in the Alps already melted?

Tags: environmental-impact

Various news media articles claim that
Two-thirds of glacier ice in the Alps 'will melt by 2100'
https://amp.theguardian.com/environment/2019/apr/09/two-thirds-glaciers-alps-alpine-doomed-climate-change-ice

That means 33% melts in 40 years.

So my question is how much did it melt in the last 40 years?

1980 to 2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [report](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Abrupt_Climate_Change.html?id=92T2d-0NBkQC&redir_esc=y) by the US Climate Change Program "virtually all the glaciers in the mid-latitudes are in a state of negative mass balance and are retreating" (2008). By how much each year and specifically in the last 40 years, is presented in the following [study](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/5/6/eaav7266) as being −5.2 ± 2.2 Gt[¹](http://antarcticglaciers.org/glaciers-and-climate/estimating-glacier-contribution-to-sea-level-rise/) (metric gigatonnes) per year during the full 1975–2016 interval (2019).

Comment: Thanks! How much is that in percentage?

Comment: 28% percent melted and 72% remaining ice in 2016